# How to Filter posts by feed targeting with Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-algorithm

I have an .NET application and I am trying to get my posts that only have a certain city specified in the feed_targeting field.

So in the example below if I run the query I get two posts returned.

Running this query:
me/posts?fields=feed_targeting

Gives me results

```
  "feed_targeting": {
    "geo_locations": {
      "cities": [
        {
          "key": 1111111
        },
        {
          "key": 2222222
        }
      ]
    }


  "feed_targeting": {
    "geo_locations": {
      "cities": [
        {
          "key": 3333333
        }
      ]
    }
```

**My Question is**

Is there a way to just query the city of 1111111 and the api will return only one post?

Comment: The API doesn’t provide any such filtering capability. If you used a user access token for a user in that city to request the data, then you should get only the posts that “match.” But other than that, all you can do is filter the results on your end.